# Explicit template instantiation syntax

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

Is the "class" keyword necessary for an explicit instantiation declaration?

```
template <class> class CL{};

template class CL<char>;  //OK
template CL<int>; //without "class"; OK for VC and clang, wrong for gcc
```

Comment: It's not really "OK" in Clang, either. `template` on the last line is a dependent-name disambiguator, so the last line is the same as just `CL<int>` -- it names the type, but doesn't constitute an explicit instantiation of the template.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thanks, you are right. I didn't know that I can write only a type in a declaration and it will work :)